# vim: Wrap current line in a /* */ comment

Tags: vim

I'm sure there are a zillion plugins to do this, but it seems so simple that I'd like to learn how to do it myself.

I want to be able to wrap the current line in a multi-line comment. I tried to do a map for this, but I don't know how to map the minus key to move to the first word in the line.

Here is the sequence of keys I'm trying to map:

```
<minus key> <insert /*> <escape insert> <$> <insert */> <escape insert>
```

Trying to map the minus key with `<S-->` did not work. How is this possible?

Comment: I recommend Tim Pope's vim-commentary: https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
nnoremap - mzI/* <esc>A */<esc>`z
```

What this does:

- `nnoremap`: start a non-recursive mapping (`nore`) in normal mode (`n` — `n` + `nore` + `map`)
- `-`: the key to map
- `mz`: set mark `z` at the current cursor position so we can come back to it when we’re done
- `I`: enter insert mode right before the first non-blank character in the current line
- `/*` : insert the opening comment string
- `<esc>`: leave insert mode
- `A`: enter insert mode right after the last non-blank character in the current line
- `*/`: insert the ending comment string
- `<esc>`: leave insert mode again
- `` `z ``: jump to the *line and column* of mark `z` (`'z` — an apostrophe instead of a backtick — would have jumped to the line, but not to the column, and we’re already on the line so we want `` `z `` to take us back to where we started)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for describing everything as well so I know what its actually doing before throwing it in my vimrc.

Comment: @user1028270 You’re welcome — glad to be able to help. :) I recommend looking around in `:help mapping` too — it’s detailed and illustrates many cool ways of using the different mapping commands.

Comment: FYI, you can get the spaces to show up by using a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) in a code block (`<code>...</code>`) instead of using backticks.

Comment: @hvd Aha! I thought there must be a way. I updated that. Many thanks. :)

Comment: I just asked another question about how to turn this into a toggle so I can toggle comments on and off. Bit lazy of me, but the docs are quite intimidating and I'd learn a lot just by seeing how this problem is solved.