# vim: Check if a line is wrapped in a comment (/* */) and toggle it on and off

Tags: vim

[Just asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386678/vim-wrap-current-line-in-a-comment) a few moments ago about how to wrap a line in a comment which yielded this fantastic snippet:

```
nnoremap - mzI/* <esc>A */<esc>`z
```

I wanted to open another thread to ask how I can turn this into a toggle. Meaning it first checks if the line is wrapped in /* */ and removes the comment or adds it if it is not there.

Does this have to be a script or can I do this with a map? Also I don't want to use a plugin for this because its simple and I would like to see how its done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
nnoremap <expr> - getline('.') =~ '^\s*/\*.\+\*/$' ? '^3x$daw' : "I/* \<esc>A */\<esc>"
```

The un-commenting is done by `^3x$daw` which deletes the beginning and ending portions of the mapping. The detection is done via a regex on the current line, `getline('.')`. I have removed the `z` mark from the comment portion of the mapping as it does a poor job of keeping cursor in the "same" spot.

This is a great example of a fancier mapping. However there are somethings to think about:

- This mapping pollutes the `.` and `"` registers.
- Only works on filetypes with c-style comments
- No visual or operator like mappings, meaning you can not mass toggle.
- Does not repeat via `.`

I highly recommend a comment plugin. I currently use Tim Pope's [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin.

For more help see:

```
:h :map-<expr>
:h getline(
```

Comment: Create a line w/ the text `hello world`. Put your cursor on the `w` and use your first mapping. The cursor is now no longer on the `w`. To me this is a bit surprising. As this mapping affects lines the cursor should probably be reset to the beginning of the line just like `>>` does.

Answer (score 2):

RE *I don't want to use a plugin for this because its simple.*

It's only simple until you use this heavily; Peter Rincker's answer already lists some issues. As you probably rely on (un-)commenting a lot, this is really a good indication for a robust, proven plugin.

Let me throw in a recommendation for [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218); it has the toggle mapping you're asking for, and supports several languages. Apart from *commentary*, also have a look at [tComment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173).